# Issues with BeautifulSoup on Python - Attribute Error

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, request, scrape

I'm just trying to do a telegram bot which sends me updates about the floor price of a NFT project. I tried with BeautifulSoup to scrape the floor price with the following code:

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib.request
    
    url = "https://magiceden.io/marketplace/bulldog_billionaires"
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    result = soup.find("div", {"p-3 bg-color-third d-flex flex-column border-radius-8px h-100 position-relative attributes-main"})
    print(result.title)
```

But it always gives me the following error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'"

Can anybode help me to solves this problem? I have to keep a eye on this NFT project so I need this bot!

I thank everyone!

Comment: The `find()` did not find a match and so returned `None`... `None.title` will give you that error. If you try printing `soup` it will show it is asking for a Captcha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This webpage is dinamically loaded so your get request won't return many of the data on the page. So when you try to find the specified data with beautifulsoup it won't find it and that's why it raises an Attribute Error.

To get around this you can use a webdriver like selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://magiceden.io/marketplace/bulldog_billionaires"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source


soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
result = soup.find("div", {"p-3 bg-color-third d-flex flex-column border-radius-8px h-100 position-relative attributes-main"})
```

This is the documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io

Comment: So that means beuaitfulsoup is only made for hard coded websites? I'm switching now to selenium!

Comment: No, the problem is not with beautifulsoup. It's just a tool to parse html code. You can still use it in this case, The problem is with how you get this data. A simple request to the website's link won't do it so you can use selenium to simulate a real user.